# How to detect when a date is selected in Angular Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I'm using the datepicker directive in Angular Bootstrap like so:

```
<datepicker ng-model="period_start" show-weeks="false" class="bs-dateselector"></datepicker>
```

How can I detect when a user has actually selected a date?

Comment: `ng-change` don't do the trick ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly as you would detect that a user has typed into an `<input ng-model="foo">` (with `ng-model`) - by using `ng-change`:

```
<datepicker ng-model="period_start" show-weeks="false" class="bs-dateselector"
            ng-change="dateChanged()"></datepicker>
```

That's the idea behind the `ngModel` directive - that other directives that `require: "ngModel"`, like `ng-change` or various validators do not need to make any assumptions about the underlying DOM of the input control.

Comment: Of course. I got confused by there not being an attribute to specify an event for when the user selected a date. And so I thought along the lines of watching a scope object or anything like that but that seemed a bit too complicated for what I was trying to achieve. Thanks!